# Entity Framework distance query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a table in SQL Server that contain `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns.
We want to query the nearest location from a specific point using the query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [ID], [Lat], [Lng],
    geography::Point(32, 34, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point([Lat], [Lng], 4326)) as Dist
FROM 
    [Area]
ORDER BY 
    Dist
```

Is there a way to do it using EF, and let the SQL Server do the distance computation?

Thanks

Comment: never tried before, but EF [have some support for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn194325) and it does exists in [EntityFramework6 Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/527ae18fe23f7649712e9461de0c90ed67c3dca9/src/EntityFramework/Spatial/DbGeometry.cs).

Comment: EF does support spatial types but distance queries are always slow, no matter the database. That's because the database has to calculate distances against *every* point in the database. You have to limit the search eg by providing range criteria for lat/long, or creating a covering image (circle or square) and select only rows included in it

Comment: Microsoft Docs explain [how to optimize nearest neighbor queries with spatial indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor) in SQL Server. There are some pretty specific criteria that have to be met for the query to use a spatial index. For example, your current query can't use a spatial index

Comment: why not write a stored procedure and bind EF to that?

Comment: What is the quantity and distribution of these points? A 100 or points in a 100 or so KM? Haversine Formula is the best but time consuming. Pythagorean is much less accurate but a lot quicker

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I've come up is just using a raw query and EF Core (I assumed you are using it) will do the rest.

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
.ToList();
```

More information about raw queries here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Also as mentioned in the comments to your question you would want add `WHERE`to your query to make it run faster. Something like this

```
WHERE [Latitude] < TopLatBound 
    AND [Latitude] > BottomLatBound 
    AND [Longitude] > LeftLngBound 
    AND [Longitude] < RightLngBound
```

You can calculate bound by converting desired maximum distance to lat and long as described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/calculating-longitude-length-in-miles